# How can a div inside a full width div have constant margin, regardless of the outer div size?

Tags: css

I have

```
<div id="1"><div id="2"></div></div>
```

`div#1` comes right after the body and has a width of `100%`
when i give `div#2` `margin:10px` the it is pushed outside the screen

How can I give `div#2` a constant padding from the edges of the screen?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't `margin: 10px` do this?

Comment: What margin are you getting at the moment then?

Comment: @Pekka I updated the question since I realized it happen only when the div is suppose to fill all the browser window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the only way to this consistently would be something like this?

```
<div id=number1><div id=number2></div></div>

#number1 {
    width:100%
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    padding:10px;
}

#number2 {
   width:auto;
   height:100px;
   background:blue;  
}
```

`#number1` could be any fixed width or percentage you want and `#number2` would fit with that minus that `padding:10px` that `#number1` has.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Udders/qFStY/

BTW: [ID tokens must begin with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

Comment: Since this is within the body, having both `width: 100%` and `padding: 10px` will result in a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

> div#1 comes right after the body and has a width of 100%

Don't give `div#1` a width then. If you don't specify its width, it will be `auto` and it will fill up the screen exactly. `div#2` will then no longer be pushed beyond the edges of the screen.

Comment: +1 for not specifying a width at all. Use this and add `padding: 10px` to your `div#1`.

Answer (score 0):

Div 2 has a width defined, probably 100%. You can't give it a width of 100% and a margin and expect it to not push out the parent div. Set the width property of div 2 to auto.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be experiencing [Collapsing Margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

You may want to instead set `padding:10px;` on div 1.

See the difference in this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/XSCDN/)

in div 1&2, 2 is set to margin 10px and collapsing margins prevents the parent div 1 from having top and bottom spacing

in div 3&4, 3 is set to padding 10px giving the spacing I think you're looking for